# Pass a function with parameters to another function in Typescript to execute

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, I want to write a method that lets me run some checks, and if those checks are successful, return the result of another method. I would like to achieve this by passing a method, complete with its parameters, to another method to execute if certain conditions are fulfilled.

If I do something like this, my code executes (fiddle [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=50&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCoAtUCVUDOIANlABQxgAOIUAagIbEBcYIAtgEaoBOANInYlYVYjF6sO3foiKcoPBtDg9JXXgEo10gN4BYAFCJElGvSaIAvCeq1GxRACpBwmKPE9EAWlkh5i5R4AbkNjHnQQHiRTOyYQgwBfQ0NQSFgEGyhedlQAExgGHgBPMioGAgI8gDFwaHgwZhq0%20oEY8xY2dRkhUjcxCU7pATkFJSgVbU1Jnn0jE2AyEYDxz0trACZEAB8tl173XitrAGYNUONEcKhIpC8ARnjzq5vS8srcprqEClt2gR6RP0ZEsxioNBp4kkDIYIAgCHBiKgAHTEODIH5ZHg5fKFEpoTA4fBEUgCACsAgALGTwY8DEA)):

```
function getTheResult(inputVal:number, multiplier:number, subtractor:number):number{
  inputVal = inputVal * multiplier - subtractor;
  return inputVal;
}

function intermediary(passedFunction:Function, inputVal:number, multiplier:number, subtractor:number, name:string):number{
  if(name == 'John')
    return -1;

  return(passedFunction(inputVal, multiplier, subtractor));
}

console.log(intermediary(getTheResult, 5, 4, 5, 'Mike'));
```

However, I would like to be able to pass `getTheResult(5,4,5)` to `intermediary(passedFunction:Function, name:string)` so that `intermediary()` can call other methods I pass, which might take a variety of different functions. For example (fiddle [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCoAtUCVUDOIANlAIwAUMYADiFAGoCGxAXGCALYBGqATgBpEnErBrEY-dl16DERblD5NocPtJ78AlBtkBvALAAoRImp1GLRAF4ztes2KIAVMNExxkvogC08kIrKqnwA3MamfOggfEjmDixhRgC%20xsagkLAIKOjYeISiAExU9pZsHJpyACYwAG4wlWq62k18hiZ2Fo42HfFOAPSI1XUNoeGIkVDRsSWOiSlGaeDQ8NNQ-Jyo1Ux8AJ4UNEwEBJsAYkuZYKxnGStCYEwbrARK1Mg65fpjMMAU9xs2tgA5AApOBYMCArRjCJRGK%20MiJMYTKb7Q7HSrXZYIChaLRzVJGYjoYQ7E4wPjPAByXBa3Woaz4Gy2uwoaEwOHwRFIlAKAgAzAIACxaIQgsEQvHGIlQEkAZVQEAQlWpnFptnp602MG2ezZuU5hQovL5IsQgIAInBUJDEUZFWACHAiQA6YhwZAUTik8lUriSu0IR0ut0er3y%203Kv22glAA)):

```
function getTheResult1(inputVal:number, multiplier:number, subtractor:number):number{
  inputVal = inputVal * multiplier - subtractor;
  return inputVal;
}

function getTheResult2(inputVal:number, dividor:number):number{
  inputVal = inputVal / dividor;
  return inputVal;
}

function intermediary(passedFunction:Function, name:string):number{
  if(name == 'John')
    return -1;

  return(passedFunction());
}

let myFirstNum:number = intermediary(getTheResult1(2,3,4), 'John');
let mySecondNum:number = intermediary(getTheResult2(2,3), 'Doe');

console.log(myFirstNum);
console.log(mySecondNum);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It seems that you are passing the result of the callback ,not the callback itself, you should write : 
`let myFirstNum:number = intermediary(() => getTheResult1(2,3,4), 'John');`

Comment: Don't use `Function` as a type? I doubt this is what you really want: https://tsplay.dev/WG2aJm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Riadh Adrani provided the correct solution in his comment.

```
let myFirstNum:number = intermediary(() => getTheResult1(2,3,4), 'John');
```

solves the problem by passing the callback instead of the result of the callback.